# QPainter, как при использовании scale можно избежать изменения текста?(или другого элемента) QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Реализовал масштабирование колесом мыши. Возможно неправильно, но на первый взгляд работает. Но, как мне можно сделать так, чтобы при масштабировании не изменялся, например,  размер текста? Если вообще возможно

```
void TraekOnSurface::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *ev)
{
    // Приблизить карту, если колесо прокрутки прокручивается вверх
    if (ev->delta() > 0)
    {
        zoom *= 1.02;
    }
    else // отдалить карту, если колесо прокрутки прокручивается вниз
    {
        zoom *= 0.98;
    }
    update();
}

void TraekOnSurface::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    int w = width(), h = height();
    QPainter pntr(this);
    pntr.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    pntr.scale(zoom, zoom); //МАСШТАБИРУЮ
    //other code
    pntr.drawText(x_rnt / delitel + 5, -y_rnt / delitel + 5,str); //ТЕКСТ
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте перед scale вызвать pntr.save(), а перед drawText pntr.restore()

Comment: @AlexanderChernin к сожалению не помогло. Я пока что сделал так: `QFont font = pntr.font(); 
 font.setPixelSize(10/zoom); pntr.setFont(font);` Это помогло, но наверное это костыль. Буду искать более адекватные методы

Comment: Нет, это не костыль - это правильно

Comment: @AlexanderChernin понял Вас, спасибо!